# Get spinner value from other class and assign it to editText

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-spinner

I am trying android application. I am that way new to Java and still learning. I am creating a spinner and trying to get value. I am trying to call the class from main page to another class. I get the toast message. Now I want to pass that value to Edit Text on the same page. Can someone guide me how to get the value in editText?

Thanks in advance!

my activity_main_page.xml

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/token_spinner"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText_order"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/token_spinner" />
```

my MainPage.Java

```
public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

        //Drop Down List Selction of Token
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.token_spinner);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.plan_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new TokenSpinner());
    }

}
```

TokenSpinner.java

```
public class TokenSpinner implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String token = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

        if (plan.equals("154")) {
            Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), "Token " + token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //I am gettin Toast here 
    //do something and assign to editText ordervalue

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your current code

Comment: Pass value using intent and set it to edit text.

Comment: Can you please add a part of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you select an item in spinner and it will be set in EditText..

```
EditText textField =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.item_edittext);
        Spinner spineer;
        spinner= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_item);
        spineer.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l{ 
        String selectedItemInSpinner=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
        textField.setText(selectedItemInSpinner);
        }
                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {}
        });
```

***Edited code***

ok i don't know it is good way or bad way but making EditText public static will solve your problem

***Mainactivity.java***

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public  static String selectedItemInSpinner="";
    Spinner spinner;
    public static EditText editText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Drop Down List Selction of Token
         spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.token_spinner);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_order);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.plan_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new TokenSpinner());
        editText.setText(selectedItemInSpinner);
    }}
```

***TokenSpinner Class***

```
public class TokenSpinner implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       MainActivity.selectedItemInSpinner=parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
        MainActivity.editText.setText(MainActivity.selectedItemInSpinner);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

***XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/token_spinner"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText_order"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am using separate class to get the value from spinner, And I want that class to assign the value to editText

Comment: by separate class you mean different activity ?

Comment: I can get the value if I include the code in MainPage.java but I want to write separate class to get the spinner value and then assign it to edittext.

Comment: i think it is what you wanted if so make it answer

Comment: thank you sang then upvote my answer and select it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it using Intent's putExtra() method. try this way,

In First Activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent ( FirstAcvity.this, SecondActivity.class ); 
intent.putExtra ( "TextBox", editText.getText().toString() );
startActivity(intent);
```

In second Activity:

```
Intent i = getIntent(); 
tring text = i.getStringExtra ( "TextBox","" ); 
secondEditText.setText ( text );
```

Comment: I dont want to take it in next activity. Its like i am taking token number and on that token number i need to define some value just after spinner.

Comment: first be clear to your question and provide your code and try.

Comment: @Sang, let's see what you have been able to do..that's seeing the code you have written, so as to get what you really want your app to perform.

Comment: but, if you want to get the value from an editText, you can always use `EditText edit_text   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);`and  `String mytext = edit_text.getText().toString()`